# My questions copied on multiple sites?

Tags: discussion

Today I get wonder,  I found my question on another site.

This is my question, [iOS : How to do proper URL encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652396/ios-how-to-do-proper-url-encoding) and this is the same question (yes, its my question asked on SO) here, http://www.coderexception.com/CNBB61NbUPSxPXiS/ios-how-to-do-proper-url-encoding

My questions?

- Why this happened?
- I read of licensing of each question asked on SE sites? If this is correct, how another site take whole question and/or answer?
- Is our question(s)/answer(s) can take out from SE sites by any one? Its permittable?
- Can I stop someone from taking my questions/answers out of SE sites?

I think, this is the only single site example I put, but there's so many sites which copied questions from SE sites.

Comment: See [Updated procedure for reporting SCRAPERs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/200177)

Comment: The site in question violates the license (all author info is removed), so feel free to follow he reporting procedure.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I've contact to SE directly. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> Why this happened?

There are a number of sites that take the content off Stack Overflow (scraping or through the data dump) and redisplay it. No idea why (probably ad revenue).

> I read of licensing of each question asked on SE sites? If this is correct, how another site take whole question and/or answer?

Attribution required. They need to link to the original and keep the names of the posters. They only seem to have added the link, though, so they are not complying with the full attribution requirements.

> Is our question(s)/answer(s) can take out from SE sites by any one? Its permittable?

Yes. When posting content on SE sites, you license them as [cc by-sa 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), with attribution required. This is linked in the footer as well.

> Can I stop someone from taking my questions/answers out of SE sites?

I don't believe so.

Comment: It really is too bad that Creative Commons doesn't have a "for the love of God, be creative" clause. I.e. even if you follow the attribution rules that if you're just making copypasta for ad revenue and not actually contributing anything then you're in violation. I'm not sure how the wording on it would go, but I would go so far to say that this kind of activity is not what CC is all about, even if it does technically follow the rules. I guess I look at the spirit of CC being you're so happy to give credit because you're standing on the shoulders of giants, which this clearly isn't doing.

Comment: @corsiKa You could add NC (non-commercial) to the license but that would kind of backfire unless SE is treated specially.

Comment: @corsiKa, the more restrictions you put in place, the more you hinder people who actually care about "the spirit" of the rule, while bad actors will always find a way to follow the letter of the rule in violation of its spirit.  This is the nature of language, it's not exact and so there will always be leeway for people to interpret in ways that aren't ideal, and people will do so.  I'd go so far as to say this isn't a bug, it's a feature, but it's not without its dangers.

Comment: I'm not saying they got it wrong. You're absolutely right - I would rather let these... knuckleheads... do what they do than to stand in the way of someone doing something truly awesome. I just wish there were a way to stop them while not stopping legitimate uses.

Comment: Not sure but looks like another same incident but this time for one of my popular question (http://asp.net.bigresource.com/asp-net-Loading-aspx-page-in-JQuery-UI-dialog--HupTUvSzU.html)

Comment: @Rahul - yep. Links back on the button, but doesn't attribute visibly to [so] or yourself. [Report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/200177)!

Comment: Thanks for conforming Oded. Reported. Just curious what action will SE team take. Any idea?

Comment: There's an attribution at the very bottom.

Comment: @MxyL - where? I didn't see the Question or Answer author names **anywhere** there.

Comment: @Oded There are links to the question.

Comment: @MxyL - so? That's not complying with the attribution requirements. Which state that author names should be included. How about you actually read the [attribution requirements](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) themselves? A link is not enough.

Comment: @Oded you should mention in your answer that links must not be `nofollow`ed too...I've seen a scrapper that linked back to SO, but also `nofollow`ed the link, making it somewhat pointless, in terms of SEO juice.

Answer (score 7):

When the site complies with the license, they can host a copy of the content here. From the footer:

> user contributions licensed under [cc by-sa 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) with [attribution required](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/)

In case the site does not comply with the license, you can report them by following the procedure on [A site (or scraper) is copying content from Stack Exchange. What should I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/200177) as indicated by @MartijnPieters.

Comment: No, you report it to SE via the [Updated procedure for reporting SCRAPERs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/200177). You linked to the *Q&A software list*, that's something different.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks, I had forgotten about that one.

Comment: These guys should be reported though - they are not complying, as they are not noting author names anywhere.

Comment: @Oded, Yes, you're right. I've contact to SE for this.